# How to remove patterns using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to display an xml file using xslt. In some nodes, i have the data between the `<code>` tag. I do not want the code tag to be displayed.

so how to remove the `<code>` and `</code>` tags alone using xslt.

I tried translate(), but it considers the pattern as separate characters, and so all the c,o,d,e are also removed from the xml content.

here is a sample xml data:

```
  <results>
  <result>
     <resultType>Error</resultType>
     <lineNum>3</lineNum>
     <columnNum>1</columnNum>
     <errorMsg>&lt;code&gt;script&lt;/code&gt; may cause screen flicker.&lt;</errorMsg>
   </result> 
   <result>   
    <resultType>Potential Problem</resultType>
    <lineNum>6</lineNum>
    <columnNum>2</columnNum>
    <errorMsg>&lt;code&gt;script&lt;/code&gt; user interface may not be accessible.&lt;
  </errorMsg>
 </result> 
 </results>
```

My xslt:

```
    <table>
     <tr class="header">
      <th>Serial Number</th>
      <th>Line Number</th>
      <th>Error Message</th>
      <th>Decision Pass</th>

     </tr>
     <xsl:for-each select="results/result">
      <xsl:if test="resultType='Potential Problem'">
        <xsl:variable name="eMsg" select="errorMsg"></xsl:variable>
        <tr class="content">  

            <td><xsl:number format="1"/></td>

            <td><xsl:value-of select="lineNum"/></td>

            <td><xsl:value-of select="errorMsg" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td>

        </tr>
      </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
```

disable-output-escaping="yes" does not work with Firefox, so trying to remove the `<code>` , `</code>` tags

Comment: I only see escaped code tags (`&lt;code&gt;`) – i.e. no real _tags_ (as in separate DOM entities)

Comment: but it gets displayed as `<code>` in the browser..

Comment: That's not the point. It confuses people trying to answer the question if you call it a tag, when in fact it has been carefully escaped to prevent it being taken as a tag.

Comment: Ohh okay.. Sorry for the confusion.. I actually am new to xml n xslt, so am nt aware of all this

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to get rid of an actual XML element you'd use something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="code">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

(assuming that you've got an identity template that copies everything else:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

)

However it looks like what you've got there is actually text you want to remove.  In this case, xsl:analyze-string is probably what you need:

```
<xsl:template match="errorMsg/text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&amp;lt;code$amp;gt;(.*)&amp;lt;/code$amp;gt;">
    <xsl:matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Some other hints and opinions: if you're using for-each when you could use a template, you ought to consider the latter.  Disable-output-escaping is the devil and should be avoided 99% of the time (or more).

Hope that does it!

Comment: Got a doubt, What is regex-group(1)?? Should it be defined else where?

Comment: regex-group is defined by analyze-string, although I think this is only available in XSLT 2 and so probably does not help you here.

Comment: Ah, did not realize that this was XSLT 1.0.

The regex-group(n) will return whatever is matched in the nth set of brackets within @regex, if that makes sense.